# API to pull all users from O365 tenant or AAD using MS graph

Tags: azure, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking for an api to pull all the users using tenant ID or using MS graph API's with an AADv1/AADv2 app.

I have both v1 and v2 apps to access MS graph and also can use o365 tenant ID.

Comment: Provide what you have done and the key code/and why you do that. This forum is for assist you resolve the issue in development but not provide pure code services.

Comment: I haven't done anything yet as I'am requesting for API endpoints . Once I know the API call I can write code to make HTTP post/get to get what I need. 

Based on my description, I have created apps on http://apps.microsoft.com to access MS graph which is the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

[Pick the appropriate SDK for the ms graph depending on your language / platform preference.](https://github.com/microsoftgraph) The readme in the repo will help you get started, as will the intellisense provided by the SDK. You’re going to want to ensure that your app registration has appropriate access to the APIs you’re after.